# Showing the norm' is non-negative

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

> Question:
>   Prove that a norm is always non-negative.

Assume that the norm is negative.

Define:
$f: \mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{-}_{0}$

$v \mapsto \left ( \vec{v} \right )f=\left \| \vec{v} \right \|$

$\left ( \vec{u}+\vec{v} \right )f=\left \| \vec{u}+\vec{v} \right \| \in \mathbb{R}^{-}_{0}$
and 
$\left ( \vec{u} \right )f=\left \| \vec{u} \right \|,\left ( \vec{v} \right )f=\left \| \vec{v} \right \|=\left \| \vec{v} \right \| \in \mathbb{R}^{-}_{0}$
[image]
At this point I am unable to progress further.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does nobody knows...?

Comment: I think nobody is answering because it is very unclear what you're asking. A norm is defined to be a function from a vector space to the non-negative reals which is positive definite, homogeneous and obeys the triangle inequality. We don't prove that a norm is non-negative; rather non-negativity is assumed as part of the definition of a norm. Besides this, your notation is a bit unclear and I'm not sure why this question is tagged with "lp-spaces".

Comment: The lecture notes issued to me are very sloppy-obviously very lazily written. I understand the frustration and I too am aware that the definition of the norm is not in the manner that I have set it out in the OP.
However, the question in my asks "Show that a norm is always non-negative" which does appears nonsensical.
An edit is made to the OP.

Comment: I think, but I am not completely certain, that non-negativity is redundant in the definition of a norm, and this can be proven by triangle inequality and homogeneity. I have done a similar exercise at least.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Usually, a norm is defined to be non-negative. But actually that is redundant.

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb K$. A norm is a function $\|\cdot\| \colon V \to \mathbb R$ with the following properties (norm axioms):

1. $\|\mathbf v\| = 0 \iff \mathbf v = \mathbf 0$
2. $\|a\mathbf v\| = |a|\|\mathbf v\|$ (scalability)
3. $\|\mathbf v + \mathbf w\| \leq \|\mathbf v\| + \|\mathbf w\|$ (triangle inequality)

for every $\mathbf v, \mathbf w \in V$ and $a \in \mathbb K$.

Now, using the fact that $\mathbf 0 = \mathbf v + (- \mathbf v)$, we have
$$0 = \|\mathbf 0\| \leq \|\mathbf v\| + \|-\mathbf v\| = 2\|\mathbf v\|$$
where we used, in order, properties $1$, $3$ and $2$.
It follows that
$$\|\mathbf v\| \geq 0.$$
In other words, even if we start with codomain $\Bbb R$ for the norm, the range is contained in $\mathbb R_0^+$.